# Is the divergence of a vector commutative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $\vec{A}\ and\ \vec{B}$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

The dot products of two vectors $\vec{A} \wedge \vec{B}$ says the commutative property holds so that

$\vec{A}.\vec{B}=\vec{B}.\vec{A}$

but what about $\vec{\nabla}.\vec{v}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The divergence is something that you apply to a (vector-valued) function. The notation $\nabla \cdot \vec{v}$ is just a visual mnemonic -- no dot product is "really" involved.

Because the operation involves two different things, asking whether it's commutative doesn't really make sense: it's like asking whether

$$\frac{d}{dx}f = f\frac{d}{dx}$$